# Fragment$InstantiationException for PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

This is a mystery for me. I don't know how to debug this situation :

The problem I have is inside the "PreferenceFragment" classes. I developped a classic "settings" interface with preference headers :

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<header 
    android:fragment="debut.telebox.Config$PrefSystemeFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_prefsysteme"
    android:title="Paramètres Système"
    android:summary="Paramètres système"
    />
<header 
    android:fragment="debut.telebox.Config$PrefChainesFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_preffavoris"
    android:title="Paramètres pour les chaînes"
    android:summary="Favoris"
    />
<header 
    android:fragment="debut.telebox.Config$PrefAproposFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="A propos"
    android:summary="A propos de TeleBox"
    />
```

The PreferenceActivity is :

```
public class Config extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ...
}

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.layout.prefentete, target);
    }

public static class PrefSystemeFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When I run this app directly on testing devices (Xoom and Nexus S under Android 4.0.4) with Eclipse, I have no problem : I am able to read and write parameters.

But when I export the app and then run it on the devices, I get the runtime error :

```
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment debut.telebox.Config$PrefSystemeFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1117)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1150)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:551)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at debut.telebox.Config.onCreate(Unknown Source)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     ... 11 more
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: debut.telebox.Config$PrefSystemeFragment
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
05-17 17:30:12.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6391):     ... 18 more
05-17 17:30:12.680: W/ActivityManager(161):   Force finishing activity debut.telebox/.Config
05-17 17:30:12.690: W/ActivityManager(161):   Force finishing activity debut.telebox/.TeleBox
```

Unfortunately, I uploaded my app on Google Play without seeing that it was not working ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it works in debug mode and not when exported, ProGuard may have done something to mangle your class name. Add the following line to your `proguard-project.txt` file in your project:

```
-keep class debut.telebox.** { *; }
```

and see if that helps.

If not, just move your `PreferenceFragment` classes into separate public Java classes, rather than using static inner classes, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with `-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add comments, I would like to add to CommonsWare answer that I noticed this happens when classes aren't referenced on java files, as Proguard's default behavior is to remove non-referenced classes for space-optimization.

I had the exact same problem as the OP's original one - using a headers file to interface my PreferenceActivity with custom extensions of PreferenceFragment, working while debugging and ClassNotFoundException'ing at Signed build. Apparently, ADT's generated source doesn't take android:fragment references in account (but then again, I haven't update ADT since AUG '13)

The solution that worked was exactly what CommonsWare suggested:

```
-keep problematicpackage.** { *; }
```

"problematicpackage" is the package where I declared my custom fragments. The ** { *; } expression includes all its contents on the -keep "directive".

One thing to note though: **YOU MIGHT NOT GET THIS PACKAGE OBFUSCATED, COMPRESSED, OR OPTIMIZED** with this "directive". I don't really care much about meta-packaging or super-copyrighting as to lose my sleep over something that should be failproof, but if you need such features, I would advise to read Proguard manual carefully.